# Full search text: one lexem after another (not immediately, but sometime later)

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I has json:

```
"mysection": [
  {
    "name": "trandmark",
    "title": {
      "en": "Brand"
    },
    "value": {
      "name": "furshet",
      "title": {
        "en": "furshet"
      }
    }
  },
```

And I want to use full search text to find "**trademark**" and "**furshet**".

To do this I use this sql:

```
select * 
from product 
where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{mysection}') @@ to_tsquery('trademark & furshet')
```

And it's success work. Nice.

But as you can see the **furshet** is always AFTER **trademark**. Not immediately, but sometime later.

So, is it  possible to use this fact in query.
Smt like this (**pseudo code**)

```
select * 
    from product 
    where to_tsvector(product.data #>> '{mysection}') @@ to_tsquery('trademark ... furshet')
```

?

Comment: I think that's what a [phrase search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-features.html#id-1.5.11.7.4.3.5.1.1) is for as you can define the "distance"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But I don't known exact distance. It's maybe 5 or maybe 10